# Careers: How to say I'm permanently unavailable?

Tags: support, jobs

I have a Careers profile, but I'm extremely happy where I'm at now. I don't want to be contacted with any job offers at all.

How can I set my profile to not be contacted with job offers at all? Is deleting my profile my only option?

```
MY PROFILE
Your profile is 131 / 210 complete
blocked employer view
published public view
```

Comment: Well, this is potentially offensive. Strongly consider changing your user name; a good idea anyway, and especially with a question title like this one.

Comment: What if his name is actually Steven Jobs?

Comment: If his name is actually Steven Jobs, then he probably shouldn't have apple.com listed as his web site.

Comment: @Charles Unless he works for apple. (heck of a coincidence though)

Comment: that and age 92? (ignoring the data on his SO profile, of course)

Comment: I guess someone read [my old post about usernames](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99914/what-are-the-rules-governing-display-names-and-avatars) and decided to try it out.

Comment: Silly question - if you are permanently unavailable, why even have a Careers profile?

Comment: @Oded because they are an awesome way to show off your awesomeness!

Comment: @Oded: Related reading: [Cryptic survey question: Why have a Careers account if not looking for employment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125888/cryptic-survey-question-why-have-a-careers-account-if-not-looking-for-employmen)

Comment: @The Establishment Isn't that the pot calling the kettle black? Yours isn't much better. I find elitism offensive, especially on a Q&A site.

Comment: @Oded I want to keep my stuff on file incase I ever start looking again. Right now I'm not looking and don't want to consider or be contacted by anyone.

Comment: @SteveJobs No, compare "The Establishment" (a harmless joke name) with "Steve Jobs" (the name of a real person). It has nothing to do with *elitism*. "The Establishment" is not the name of a real person, living or dead. Humorous names are acceptable, but when you use *someone else's name* you're going into a gray area.

Comment: Yes, I switched my name precisely because of all the people complaining about perceived "elitism" here. It's a tongue-in-cheek jab at them, all in good fun—something that we have a lot of on Meta. As The Other Person Named After A Thing says, there's no risk of anyone confusing me with a real person (other than myself, of course) who is living or dead. Moreover, **context is key**. I'd think nothing of your user name (well, I might think something, but I'd certainly *say* nothing) if you hadn't used it to post a question with this title. The phrase "permanently unavailable" is offensive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you select "Block all messages and searches" on your profile (which it looks like you have), you will not receive any messages from employers through Careers.

If your profile is public and indexable in Google, it's always possible that they'll find it and track down your contact details by other means, but they cannot send you a message in Careers.

**Update**

If you reply "Not Interested" to the message and then select "I'm no longer looking for a job", we automatically opt you out of future messages from employers.  That was the source of confusion in this case: OP received a message, replied, and then checked their profile to opt out of future ones and discovered they were already opted out (but only for the past few seconds)

Comment: But I was contacted with an offer even though I have that set already? Their message appears in my Careers inbox.

Comment: @SteveJobs Looking at your history, it looks like you were set to contactable until today

Comment: That's strange, I don't think I changed anything. Maybe I just had to log in for the settings to update themselves, I know I hadn't logged into Careers in a very, very long time.

Comment: @Steve if you reply "Not interested" to the message and select "I'm no longer looking for a job" we automatically opt you out of future messages

Comment: That's exactly what happened! Thanks so much for this feature, I really like it!